# How to set variable JMSCorrelationID in IBM BPEL flow?

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, correlation, bpel

I have a webservice request that is handled by BPEL flow. This BPEL flow puts this message on a Queue using MQ JMS Import Binding. It contains a response queue information as well. I need to set custom correlationID or JMSMessageID value into CorrelationID so that BPEL flow can correlate the response to request. Please suggest if you have some idea.

Answer (score 0):

JMSMessageID should **not** be set by an application. If it is set, during a message send, it will be ignored. When the send method returns, the JMSMessageID will be set to a JMS Provider assigned value. When a message is received, it will have a provider assigned unique value. Note JMSMessageID is unique.

```
Quoting from JMS 1.1 Specs:
```

*A client can use the JMSCorrelationID header field to link one message with another. A typical use is to link a response message with its request message. Since each message sent by a JMS provider is assigned a message ID value, it is convenient to link messages via message ID. All message ID values must start with the ‘ID:’ prefix.*

*In some cases, an application (made up of several clients) needs to use an application-specific value for linking messages. For instance, an application may use JMSCorrelationID to hold a value referencing some external information. Application-specified values must not start with the ‘ID:’ prefix; this is reserved for provider-generated message ID values.*

To set JMSCorrelationID, application need to call `setJMSCorrelationID` method of `JMSMessage` class with String parameter.